# Show progress mask when HTML form post back and downloads file

Tags: javascript, html

I am newbie to javascript and HTML. I am working on to show busy image while my html form is post back and download the file. I am using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object plugin. I am using IE 9. I am posting back a form and in return receive a file.

When I am posting back I see the busy mask then IE ask me to save as the file but the mask doesn't go away. No success/Error callback is getting called. Below is the snapshot of my code.

Highly appreciate your guidance in resolving this.

```
`frmExport.html
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script src="js/frmExport.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="......">
<form id="frmExport" onsubmit="return exportFile();" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend class="cuesGroupBoxTitle">Export File</legend>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8">
        <tr>
        <td width="50%">Export File:</td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="ExportFileButton" value="Export" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>

frmExport.js

function exportSuccess(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
{ 
hideMask("exportFile");
alert(statusText");
}

function exportError()
{
hideMask("exportFile");
alert("An error occurred while exporting file.");
}

function exportFile() 
{
if(confirm("Exporting file may take sometime. Do you want to continue?"))
{
    var options = 
    { 
        type:          "POST",
        success:       exportSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
        error:         exportError,
        url:           'exportURI',
        dataType:      'text'
    }; 

    // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#frmExport').submit(function() 
    { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        showMask("exportFile");

        //always return false
        return false; 
    });
}
}`
```

Comment: 1. removed the onsubmit from form tag 2. changed `<td><input type="submit" id="ExportFileButton" value="Export" onclick="return exportFile();"/></td>`    Now my success callback is getting called but IE doesn't ask to Save As the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that you hook the submit event (`$('#frmExport').submit(...)`) when the submit has already been triggered. Try hooking it on the document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = 
{ 
    type:          "POST",
    success:       exportSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
    error:         exportError,
    url:           'exportURI',
    dataType:      'text'
}; 

// bind to the form's submit event 
$('#frmExport').submit(function() 
{ 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    showMask("exportFile");

    //always return false
    return false; 
});

});
```

Comment: I have other forms too on the HTML page. Where should I write this? In the HEAD section?

Comment: The $(document).ready function waits for your page to be fully loaded before it's called, so you can put it in the HEAD section, but you could also put it somewhere else that fits your needs, and it will still be called at the right time.

Comment: It doesn't help. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. I copied it to the head section. I reloaded the page and it gave me confirmation message.